# How can I delete mail on iPhone?

Tags: gmail, iphone

How can I delete mail on iPhone using Gmail app ?
Is it possible to delete emails, instead of archiving ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the email and you'll have two icons on the top. One is for archive and one's for bin.